# Display Handlers on Hover (fabric js)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js for resizing, rotating..etc of canvas. I want to display the handlers only when the cursor is hover and hide them when cursor is out. Will it possible with fabric js??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

every object support `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

You can change the property `object.hasControls` (boolean) setting it to true on mouse over and false on mouseout